# Why is sscan showing keys that don't exist?

Tags: redis

I run `sscan A 0`, and the first key in the list is X. But X does not exist. ttl X gives -2, exists X gives 0, get X gives (nil), and yet when I run sscan it still shows up in the list.

More, `info keyspace` says that there are 594620 keys total. However, `scard A` says there are 1211593. So, there are twice as many keys in the set than there are in the whole database? How does that work???

How can I get an *accurate* count of the number of keys in the set?

Comment: You can use `SCARD` to get the number of keys/members in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the *members* of a set with *keys* in the database. The only key here is `A`. The members of `A` are not keys.

Now, it may be that you're using the *names* of keys as the string-valued members of your `A`, but nevertheless they are not keys.